# Optimize File Download

Tags: java, http, get

I am trying to optimize my code when downloading around 129 reports from a server. All of the reports have different URLs and here is the code I have developed:

```
public static void getReport(String eqID, String reportCode, String reportName, String fileName) throws IOException{

        String url = "http://example.com/api?function=getData&eqId=" + eqID;
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        Authenticator.setDefault (new Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication ("username", "password".toCharArray());
            }
        });

        // optional default is GET
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();

        if(responseCode == 200){
            System.out.println("Downloading: " + reportName);
            File file = new File("C:/Users/fileName);

            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(con.getInputStream());
            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file.getPath()));

            int i = 0;
            while ((i = bis.read()) != -1) {
                bos.write(i);
            }

            bos.flush();
            bis.close();
            bos.close();
        }
        else if(responseCode == 204){
            System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to: " + reportName);
            System.out.println("Response: Successful but report is empty. It will be skipped");
        }
    }
```

The issue is that it's taking too much time to process these downloads. Between all 129 reports its around 25MB and I have a High-Speed Internet Connection. I'm fairly new to downloading files through java and need some help. I call this method 129 times in total.

If you can recommend ways to optimize it or just use on HTTP Connection instead of opening 129 individually.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using Java 7?

Comment: In addition to increasing your buffer size (as noted below), you might consider adding a [thread pool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool_pattern).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch a thread pool cannot do anything to increase bandwidth though ;)

Comment: @ElliottFrisch nor incrementing the speed of disk =\

Comment: @fge While true when considering an ideal point-to-point connection model, the internet is not that. Well implemented parallel transfers can outperform serial transfers. See also [aria2](http://aria2.sourceforge.net/) and modern peer-to-peer systems.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Write buffers and read buffers might help, but there you have me. Any true storage speed limitations are fundamental limits. Of course, SSDs and RAID systems have the potential to scale systems out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bottleneck is here:

```
int i = 0;
while ((i = bis.read()) != -1) {
    bos.write(i);
}
```

You're reading byte by byte, which can take a lot of time in bigger files. Instead, read the file by chunks, usually on 4KB or 8KBs:

```
int FILE_CHUNK_SIZE = 1024 * 4; //to make it easier to change to 8 KBs
byte[] chunk = new byte[FILE_CHUNK_SIZE];
int bytesRead = 0;
while ((bytesRead = input.read(chunk)) != -1) {
    bos.write(chunk, 0, bytesRead);
}
```

---

Another alternative would be using [`IOUtils#copy`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#copy%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.io.OutputStream%29) from [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) which already does this for you:

```
IOUtils.copy(bis, bos);
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to try it now and let you know how it went.

Comment: Note, if using Java 7, it is better to use `Files.copy()`; there is one version of it taking an `InputStream` as a first argument and a `Path` as the second one! And of course you can specify copy options as well

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza - This part of the code: bytesRead = input.read(buffer)... I think instead of buffer you meant chunk ?

Comment: @WiloMaldonado yes, my mistake. Fixed.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza It's running much faster now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 7, it is very easy. When you want to write the file, do:

```
final Path dstFile = Paths.get("C:/users/filename");

if (responseCode == 200) {
    try (
        final InputStream in = con.getInputStream();
    ) {
        Files.copy(in, dstFile, StandardOpenOption.CREATE_NEW);
    }
} // etc
```